# Understanding F# inline & statically resolved type parameters: F# casting example

Tags: generics, f#, type-parameter

F#'s inline functions with statically resolved generic parameters seem to be similar to C++'s templates. However, unlike C++, you need to specify the constraints - how does that work?

For example, I'm trying to implement an upcasting function, but this won't work:

```
let inline myUpcast< ^a, ^b  when ^a :> ^b  > (x: ^a) :  ^b =  x
```

The error message is: error FS0698: Invalid constraint: the type used for the constraint is sealed, which means the constraint could only be satisfied by at most one solution.

I'm actually trying to write a function that will cast sequences when the underlying types can be cast (to work around lack of covariance), but the following doesn't quite work either:

```
let inline upcastseq (xs: seq< ^a >) : seq< ^b > when ^a :> ^b = xs :?> seq< ^b >
```

which causes the following warning: warning FS0064: This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'a has been constrained to be type ' ^b'.  As might be expected then, actually using the function doesn't work as hoped.

So, I'm looking for a function that will cause a type-check error if used to convert sequences in a covariantly invalid fashion (hence the generic parameter restriction) - is such a thing possible?

A little more generally, what are the limitations of statically resolved type parameters as compared to C++'s templates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible, but it's unrelated to static member constraints.  Using normal generic constraints is equally doomed, for the same reason:

```
// doesn't work
let myUpcast<'a, 'b when 'a :> 'b) (x: 'a) : 'b = unbox (box x)
```

Basically F# does not allow type constraints involving two different type parameters; they are always constrained to be equal.

See my answer to [How to constrain one type parameter by another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857474/how-to-constrain-one-type-parameter-by-another) for more commentary.

Comment: Isn't it kinda weird that F# (whose type-inference is supposed to be a selling point) can't do such basic constraints, yet C# (and of course the CLR) actually support it?  Frustrating.

Comment: @Eamon - it's very frustrating, but I wouldn't classify these constraints as "basic".  I'd guess that at less than 5% of C# programmers will ever use a type parameter constrained by another type parameter.