# Bug in F# 2.0 wrt to where constraints in generic type parameters?

Tags: c#, generics, f#, c#-to-f#, f#-3.0

If I have a C# method that I want to consume from F# and receives two typed parameters like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static void GenericMethodWithTwoTypeParamsThatHaveAWhereClass<TA, TB>() where TA : TB
    {

    }
}
```

When I try to call it via F#, the compiler complains:

```
Foo.GenericMethodWithTwoTypeParamsThatHaveAWhereClass<System.IO.BinaryWriter, System.IDisposable>()
```

So, is this a bug in F# 2.0?

Comment: Can you post the error message you get from the F# compiler?

Comment: Daniel's right.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857474/how-to-constrain-one-type-parameter-by-another.

Comment: @JackP. You can see the error message in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This type of constraint is not supported in F#. The [spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc321997258) indicates constraints of the form `t1 :> t2` are treated as `t1 = t2`, which explains your error:

> This expression was expected to have type BinaryWriter but here has type System.IDisposable

Depending how `TB` is used, you might be able to get by with

```
GenericMethodWithTwoTypeParamsThatHaveAWhereClass<BinaryWriter, _>()
```

`TB` will be inferred as `BinaryWriter`, according to the aforementioned rule. However, if that works then your C# method can likely do with one type param.

Comment: Do you know if this is fixed in F# 3.0?

Comment: It's by design...and unchanged in 3.0.