# Statically typed Context

Tags: f#

I am looking to encode (in some .NET language -- fsharp seems most likely to support) a class of types that form a current context.

The rules would be that we start with an initial context of type 'a. As we progress through the computations the context will be added to, but in a way that I can always get previous values. So assume an operation that adds information to the context, 'a -> 'b, that infers that all elements of 'a are also in 'b.

The idea is similar to an immutable map, but I would like it to be statically typed. Is that feasible? How, or why not? TIA.

Update: The answer appears to be that you cannot quite do this at this time, although I have some good suggestions for modeling what I am looking for in a different way. Thanks to all who tried to help with my poorly worded question.

Comment: If I understand you, the first thing that comes to mind is a tuple. You could have a function `'a -> 'a * 'b`. Granted the type could get messy with nested tuples, but for a handful of transformations it's quick and easy.

Comment: type Context<'a, 'b, 'c when 'c :> 'a>(f:'a -> 'b -> 'c, v:'a, v1:'b) = 
    member x.Current:'c = f( v, v1)

Comment: ...sorry, not very good at this editor. The code above is close to constraints of the type I am looking for.
I would actually prefer to 'a and 'c to be immutable.

Comment: Trying to figure out what you're trying to achieve. How are types 'a, 'b, 'c supposed to be related to each other? In your example 'c is a subtype of 'a, why is it important? When you're talking about an operation that adds information to the context, you make it sound as if both 'a and 'b are collections. If so, why can't they be the same type? If not, what do you mean by "all elements of 'a being in 'b"?

Comment: Do you mean a process that starts with an 'a, then proceeds through a series of steps where you refine the context with data of type 'b, and produces an object of 'c from initial 'a and the collected 'b values?

Comment: Or a process where each step adds information of a completely different type, so instead of a homogeneous collection of 'b, you have a chain of heterogeneous values, say, 'b0, 'b1, ..., 'bn?

Comment: @Daniel ...thanks, but I think I am trying to avoid the nesting (otherwise it seems right).

Comment: @scrwtp:
Thanks for trying to understand. Let me try to be more clear.
If I have an operation that returns a name as a string, it could be:
`type Name = { Name:string }`

And then if I have another operation that returns an amount, and add it to the context:
`type NameAndAmount = { Name:string; Amount:decimal }`

If you thought of Name and NameAndAmount as interfaces in .NET, you could consider NameAndAmount to implement Name. I am trying to enforce that relationship -- it would be similar to a (labled) tuple, but the tuples would soon get very nested.

Comment: Ok, I see. You're modeling a heterogeneous map, like a clojure map or javascript object, using a series of more or less detailed records. I don't think it's a good design in general. I can see it becoming unmaintainable rather quickly. I'll look at adding a proper answer later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate record types in F# are distinct, even if superficially they have similar structure. Even if the fields of record 'a form a subset of fields of record 'c, there's no way of enforcing that relationship statically. If you have a valid reason to use distinct record types there, the best you could do would be to use reflection to get the fields using `FSharpType.GetRecordFields` and check if one forms the subset of the other.

Furthermore, introducing a new record type for each piece of data added would result in horrendous amounts of boilerplate.

I see two ways to model it that would feel more at place in F# and still allow you some way of enforcing some form of your 'a :> 'c constraint at runtime.

1) If you foresee a small number of records, all of which are useful in other parts of your program, you can use a discriminated union to enumerate the steps of your process:

```
type NameAndAmountAndFooDU = 
    | Initial of Name
    | Intermediate of NameAndAmount
    | Final of NameAndAmountAndFoo
```

With that, records that previously were unrelated types 'a and 'c, become part of a single type. That means you can store them in a list inside Context and easily go back in time to see if the changes are going in the right direction (Initial -> Intermediate -> Final).

2) If you foresee a lot of changes like 'adding' a single field, and you care more about the final product than the intermediate ones, you can define a record of option fields based on the final record:

```
type NameAndAmountAndFooOption =
    {
        Name: string option
        Amount: decimal option
        Foo: bool option
    }
```

and have a way to convert it to a non-option NameAndAmountAndFoo (or the intermediate ones like NameAndAmount if you need them for some reason). Then in Context you can set the values of individual fields one at a time, and again, collect the previous records to keep track of how changes are applied.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
type Property = 
    | Name of string
    | Amount of float

let context = Map.empty<string,Property>

//Parse or whatever
let context = Map.add "Name" (Name("bob")) context
let context = Map.add "Amount" (Amount(3.14)) context
```

I have a feeling that if you could show us a bit more of your problem space, there may be a more idiomatic overall solution.

Comment: In the code:

`type Context<'a, 'b, 'c when 'c :> 'a>(f:'a -> 'b -> 'c, v:'a, v1:'b) = 

    member x.Current:'c = f v v1 ` 


Why is `'a` sealed? Couldn't `'a` be `INamed` and `'c` be `INamedAndAmount` (to use some C# naming conventions)?

Comment: @RobertSchroeder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857474/how-to-constrain-one-type-parameter-by-another