# Is it possible to implement the IDbSet<T> interface in F#?

Tags: entity-framework, f#

I am attempting to make a mock implementation of [`IDbSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679233%28v=vs.113%29.aspx), and I happen to be doing it in F#.

```
type MockDbSet<'T when 'T : not struct>(items:seq<'T>) =
    let collection = ResizeArray(items)

    new () = MockDbSet(Seq.empty)

    interface IDbSet<'T> with
        member x.Add entity = collection.Add entity; entity
        member x.Attach entity = collection.Add entity; entity
        member x.Remove entity = collection.Remove entity |> ignore; entity
        member x.Create() = Unchecked.defaultof<'T>
        member x.Create<'TD when 'TD : not struct and 'TD :> 'T>() = Unchecked.defaultof<'TD>
        member x.Find([<ParamArray>] values) = raise <| NotImplementedException()
        member x.Local = Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(collection)

    interface System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<'T> with
        member x.GetEnumerator() = 
            collection.GetEnumerator() :> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<_>

    interface System.Collections.IEnumerable with
        member x.GetEnumerator() =
            collection.GetEnumerator() :> System.Collections.IEnumerator

    interface IQueryable<'T> with
        member x.ElementType = typeof<'T>
        member x.Expression =
            collection.AsQueryable().Expression
        member x.Provider =
            collection.AsQueryable().Provider
```

Everything is fine, except for this line:

```
member x.Create<'TD when 'TD : not struct and 'TD :> 'T>() = Unchecked.defaultof<'TD>
```

...which gives me these compiler errors:

> error FS0698: Invalid constraint: the type used for the constraint is
>   sealed, which means the constraint could only be satisfied by at most
>   one solution
>
> warning FS0064: This construct causes code to be less
>   generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'TD
>   has been constrained to be type ''T'.
>
> error FS0663: This type
>   parameter has been used in a way that constrains it to always be ''T
>   when 'T : not struct'
>
> error FS0661: One or more of the explicit class
>   or function type variables for this binding could not be generalized,
>   because they were constrained to other types

This line is attempting to implement [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696581%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=fsharp), which according to that page has the following signature in C#:

```
TDerivedEntity Create<TDerivedEntity>()
where TDerivedEntity : class, TEntity
```

And this signature in F#:

```
abstract Create : unit -> 'TDerivedEntity  when 'TDerivedEntity : not struct and 'TEntity
```

When I try to use the example F# signature, I get a variety of syntax errors, which doesn't surprise me because that signature doesn't even look like valid F#.

I'm not really sure what to make of these error messages, or how to write my constraints to satisfy both the interface and the F# compiler. I'm starting to wonder if it's even possible to implement this particular Microsoft interface in this particular Microsoft programming language. Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method `Create` needs a subtype constraint between 2 generic type parameters. I'm afraid there is no way to add a subtype constraint to a generic type parameter based on another one in F#. They're always assumed to be equal, see the [spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335819033)  *New constraints of the form type :> 'b are solved again as type = 'b.*

See this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857474/how-to-constrain-one-type-parameter-by-another) to a similar problem.

We should request to include [this](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/255) feature in the next F# version.

Comment: I don't think that UserVoice suggestion is completely relevant - while naked constraints would be one means of working around F#'s lack of generic {co,contra}-variance they're really a different feature, and adding generic variance without adding naked constraints wouldn't solve this issue.

Comment: @kvb I agree, it's related but we should either reformulate it or suggest it separately. Even if we don't have co/contra-variance I would like to be able to add this kind of constraints. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, it absolutely makes sense to create a new feature request covering the actual scenario here.  It's rare, but it's a huge pain that some libraries are unusable from F#, and there's no workaround.

Answer (score 3):

I was very disappointed by this at first. I still am in some ways, but there is a workaround in EF6. You can inherit `DbSet<'TEntity>` directly, and use overrides to implement the collection in memory. This will suffice for most cases; you can inherit from this type if you want a concrete implementation of `Find`.

```
type FakeDbSet<'TEntity when 'TEntity : not struct>(items: seq<'TEntity>) =
    inherit DbSet<'TEntity>()
    let data = ObservableCollection<'TEntity>(items)
    let query = data.AsQueryable()
    new() = FakeDbSet(Seq.empty)
    override __.Add(item: 'TEntity) = data.Add(item); item
    override __.Remove(item: 'TEntity) = data.Remove(item) |> ignore; item
    override __.Attach(item: 'TEntity) = data.Add(item); item
    override __.Create() = Activator.CreateInstance<'TEntity>()
    override __.Local with get() = data
    interface System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<'TEntity> with
        member __.GetEnumerator() = data.GetEnumerator() :> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<_>
    interface System.Collections.IEnumerable with
        member __.GetEnumerator() = data.GetEnumerator() :> System.Collections.IEnumerator
    interface IQueryable<'TEntity> with
        member __.ElementType = typeof<'TEntity>
        member __.Expression = query.Expression
        member __.Provider = query.Provider
```