# Is it possible to write a genericFunction<’T> where ‘T is constrained to be a tuple of type 'T2*'T3?

Tags: generics, f#

Is it possible in F# to write a generic function where you specify a type 'T, but constrain 'T to be a tuple of type 'T2*'T3?

Here's a couple of things I've tried that just produces compiler errors:

```
let fun1<'T when 'T :> 'T2*'T3> () = …
let fun2<'T, 'T2, 'T3 when 'T :> 'T2*'T3> () = …
```

(In fun2 'T2/'T3 would ideally be inferred by 'T1.)

The reason I want to do this is that I'm writing an application with an in-memory database, and I'm trying to write a generic function which extracts data associated with a database-entity in the specified tuple-form. I have a solution that works, but has a few drawbacks:

```
let workingExtractEntity<'T> (id : EntityID) (db: Database) : EntityID*'T =
        let t = db.GetEntityComponent id typeof<'T>
        (id, t)
```

As well as similar functions with more type arguments:

```
let workingExtractEntity2<'T1, 'T2> (id : EntityID) (db: Database) : EntityID*'T1*'T2 = …
```

The main problem with this approach is that you have to manually type in and order the generic arguments every time you use the function. I would have preferred being able to specify a single tuple type instead, in combination with type aliases for commonly used tuple types, like so:

```
//Obviously won’t compile, but illustrates what I would like to do.
let extractEntity2<'T when 'T :> EntityID*'T2*'T3> id db : 'T =
        let t2 = db.GetEntityComponent id typeof<'T2>
        let t3 = db.GetEntityComponent id typeof<'T3>
        (id, t2, t3)

type Player = EntityID*Position*Health
    
let extractPlayer id db : Player = extractEntity2<Player> id db
```

Note that no objects of type Player are stored in the database, but rather only the components that make up a Player, namely Position and Health, are stored there. (Any entity with a Position and Health associated with it could be represented as a Player.)

Is there any way to achieve something like this?

Comment: Why do you need to use generics? Couldn't you just let the type inference determine the type of the function? Or use type annotations, if needed or desired. Of course, you probably need to define types for EntityID, Position, and Health (looks like you've done that, but are not revealing the type definitions here).

Comment: @ScottHutchinson I need generics to be able to reuse the same function for different types: It is possible to remove generics from extractEntity2 and rename it to “extractPlayer”, replacing all references to ‘T2 and ‘T3 with Position and Health. But this new extractPlayer function would only be capable of extracting a Player, and you would have to create almost identical functions for extractMonster and extractFloorTile and so on… In regards to type inference: The return type of the functions in my example code could probably be inferred, I’ve just included them for clarity.

Comment: Consider making Player/Monster/FloorTile a generic class instead of a tuple. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/classes#generic-type-parameters

Comment: I think this issue might be related to what you are trying to do. https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/629

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve done some research and I think I have found the answer to my own question:

Unfortunately what I want to do seems not to be possible in F#, and reason is nicely summarized [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23643989/is-it-possible-to-implement-the-idbsett-interface-in-f) by the user Gus:

> I'm afraid there is no way to add a subtype constraint to a generic
> type parameter based on another one in F#. They're always assumed to
> be equal, see the spec *New constraints of the form type :> 'b are
> solved again as type = 'b*.

This limitation doesn’t exist in C#, which makes interop troublesome sometimes. There is an [issue](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/255) on the F# language suggestion github page addressing it.

In other words you can’t write a function like this:

```
let foo<'T, 'U when 'T :> 'U> () = …
```

And it means you can’t do this either:

```
let foo2<'T, 'T2, 'T3 when 'T :> Tuple<'T2, 'T3>> () = …
```

Which is essentially what I wanted, except with additional type inference, so that instead of typing out the whole:

```
let callFoo2 = foo2<int*string, int, string> ()
```

You could just write it like this, and have 'T2 and 'T3 be inferred from 'T1:

```
let callFoo2Differently = foo2<int*string> ()
```