# F#: implementing "try cast" function, parameterized "subtype of" constraint doesn't work

Tags: c#, f#, c#-to-f#

I'm trying to implement a "try cast" operator in F#. The subtype of constraint isn't working.

By example, what I want to do in C#:

```
static A TryCast<TSuper, TSub, A>(
    Func<TSub, A> f,
    Func<TSuper, A> g,
    TSuper x)
    where TSub : TSuper
    =>
    x is TSub sub ? f(sub) : g(x);
```

The equivalent in F# should be:

```
let tryCast<'super, 'sub when 'sub :> 'super>
    (f : 'sub -> 'a) (g: 'super -> 'a) (x : 'super) : 'a =
        match x with
        | :? 'sub as sub -> f sub
        | x              -> g x
```

Or

```
... 
if x :? 'sub then f (x :?> 'sub) else g x
```

However, it gives me an error "'sub has been constrained to always be 'super" in the "when" clause.
This seems to indicate F# doesn't support this. I find it odd that I can do it in C#, though.

So the question is: can this be done in F#?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the link explaining that it is indeed an F# limitation:
[How to constrain one type parameter by another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857474/how-to-constrain-one-type-parameter-by-another)

I'd like to share the (sub-optimal) workaround I have found for the specific case I was tackling:

```
let tryCastWith
    (success : 'sub -> 'a) (fallback: 'super -> 'a) (x : 'super) : 'a =
    let o = box x
    if o :? 'sub then success (o :?> 'sub) else fallback x
```

More specifically, the function I actually wanted was something like this:

```
let tryCast (x : 'super) : Choice<'sub, 'super> =
    tryCastWith Choice1Of2 Choice2Of2 x
```

Which decouples the casting and consumption. In order to use this second function, it will be necessary to either have F# infer what 'sub is or give an explicit type annotation, however.