# Is there already or can I declare a more pipe friendly upcast?

Tags: f#

I want to be able to just

`let upcast'<'T,'TResult when 'T :> 'TResult> (y:'T) = y |> upcast`

However, that then constrains `'T` to be `'TResult` instead of it being something that can be cast to `'TResult`

I know I can

1. `|> fun x -> x :> 'TResult`
2. `|> fun x -> upcast x`
3. `|> fun x -> x :> _`

but then if I'm doing anything else on that line I have to go back and put `()` around the `fun x -> upcast x` or it thinks what I'm doing is part of the `fun x` function.

can I define or does there exist a way to be able to

`|> upcast |>` doesn't work

`|> ( ( :> ) 'TResult)` doesn't work and is messy

*edit*
In response to Thomas Petricek - minimal failing auto-upcast sample:

```
module Test =
    let inline f'<'t>():IReadOnlyCollection<'t> =
        List.empty
        |> ResizeArray
        |> System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection
        |> fun x -> x :> IReadOnlyCollection<_>

    let inline f<'t> () :IReadOnlyCollection<'t> =
        List.empty
        |> ResizeArray
        |> System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection
```

Comment: in the edit, the 2nd example fails, while the first works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

much simpler and unexpected

```
let inline f2<'t>() : IReadOnlyCollection<'t> = 
    List.empty
    |> ResizeArray
    |> System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection
    :> _
```

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, specifying the kind of constraint between `'T` and `'TResult` is not possible. There is a related [question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857474/how-to-constrain-one-type-parameter-by-another) with links to more information and a feature request.

That said, I wonder why do you need this? The F# compiler is able to insert upcasts automatically, even when using pipes, so if you want to do this as part of a longer pipe, it should not be needed. Here is a simple illustration:

```
type Animal = interface end
type Dog = inherit Animal 

let makeDog () = { new Dog }
let consumeAnimal (a:Animal) = 0

makeDog () |> consumeAnimal
```

I guess you might need pipe-able upcast if you wanted to have it at the end of the pipeline, but then I'd just do the upcast on a separate line. Or is your question motivated by some more complicated cases where the implicit upcast does not work?

**EDIT 1:** Here is a minimal example using `ReadOnlyCollection` and `IReadOnlyList` which works:

```
let foo () : System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<int> = failwith "!"
let bar (x:System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<int>) = 0

foo() |> bar
```

**EDIT 2:** To comment on the update - the problem here is that automatic upcasts are only inserted when passing arguments to functions, but in the second example, the type mismatch is between the result of the pipe and the return type of the function. You can get that to work by adding an identity function of type `IReadOnlyCollection<'T> -> IReadOnlyCollection<'T>` to the end of the pipe:

```
let inline f<'t> () :IReadOnlyCollection<'t> =
    List.empty
    |> ResizeArray
    |> System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection
    |> id<IReadOnlyCollection<_>>
```

This works, because now the upcast is inserted automatically when passing the argument to the `id` function - and this then returns a type that matches with the return type of the function.

Comment: Yeah auto upcast from `ReadOnlyCollection<_>` to `IReadOnlyList<_>` doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Maslow My trivial test (see edit) worked - it would be interesting to see a small counter-example for this - I suspect there is one, because the auto-upcasts are not perfect, but I'm not sure what exactly it needs to look like...

Comment: dammit, I was in an edit frenzy on the question and edited your answer on accident, and I'm not sure I can undo that

Comment: @Maslow Thanks for the example! This is actually a bit different situation - see my Edit 2!