# F# type constrains subtyping

Tags: class, inheritance, f#, type-constraints, subtyping

I got a question, mostly because I found a case where classes and subtyping was needed.

let say we got some function

```
let IsA<'item, 'input> (subject: 'input) = 
    match subject with
    | :? 'item as item -> Some item
    | _ -> None
```

is there a way to constraint the generic types to allow this.

The alternative is to do a IsA function for all subtype constrains.

This is a dummy case, but it clearly describes what I need to do.

Comment: found a way if i know the 'input type upfront, but would still like to know if it is possible for two generic types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your motivation here is. You can certainly `box` the `subject` before pattern matching on the value:

```
let IsA<'item, 'input> (subject: 'input) = 
    match box subject with
    | :? 'item as item -> Some item
    | _ -> None
```

This lets you call `IsA` on various things, including the ones that make sense (but also, because of the boxing, some that cannot possibly make sense). You need to constrain the `'item` type parameter, either by explicitly saying `IsA<Cat, _>` or by having an annotation elsewhere:

```
type Animal() = class end
type Dog() = inherit Animal()
type Cat() = inherit Animal()
let dogAnimal = Dog() :> Animal

let asCat : Cat option = IsA dogAnimal
let asDog : Dog option = IsA dogAnimal
let asCat2 : Cat option = IsA (System.Random())
```

In principlie, it would be nice if the last case with `Random` was not allowed. Unfortunately, you cannot specify a constraint for this though. The following does not work:

```
let IsA<'item, 'input when 'item :> 'input> (subject: 'input) = 
    match subject with
    | :? 'item as item -> Some item
    | _ -> None
```

The issue is discussed, for example, here: [How to constrain one type parameter by another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857474/how-to-constrain-one-type-parameter-by-another)

Comment: That was what I needed. forgot about box
I'm using subclasses as token types for a toy lexer/parser. DU makes it less pretty for this part, and any DU with many cases are inefficient because of the memory model.

The reason I wanted to know if and how it was possible for to generic types, was because it might be nice to have around, can see cases where it would help a lot.

Comment: it also makes it much more concise to be able to write parse<Binop>

Comment: In the above example, if you turn that into `let IsA<'item> (subject:obj) = ...` then you will eliminate the additional type parameter and will be able to say just `IsA<Dog>` - and implicit conversion should make it possible to write just `IsA<Dog> dogAnimal`.

Comment: I know that, but thanks anyway.